# Excel, Copy sheet with formulas to new workbook, replace existing reference

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet with many formulas. I am trying to copy them into a new workbook however the formulas reference the previous workbook.

How can I replace the previous workbook reference in these formulas?

I have tried find and replace,
Find What: `'[workbook v1.1.xlsm]` 
ReplaceWith :  `""` , i've also tried just leaving this field blank.

I get the following error:

"We found a problem with the following formula"

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: You can use Find and Replac- Options>> - Look in: Formulas- change the data in Formula you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was able to to go Data -> Edit Links -> Then choose the current workbook from the file picker. It got rid of all other workbook references I had.